# finding index of object in array in js accordign to value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my array like callsData[] which contains objects like following:

```
{
  "caller_id": "110",
  "Channel": "SIP/Kam-SBC-0000001c",
  "AccountCode": "1004",
  "Server": "192.168.1.36",
  "Callee": "109",
  "connected_line": "109",
  "Uniqueid": "145712272845",
  "DestChannel": "SIP/Kam-SBC-0000001d",
  "DestUniqueid": ["3432423423423","123123123","312321312"]
}
```

I want to find index of object where my value 3432423423423 is present in the DestUniqueid array.

Comment: `$.inArray(obj.DestUniqueid, '3432423423423')` or `obj.DestUniqueid.indexOf('3432423423423');`

Comment: Thanks but how can i find the index?

Comment: I am doing something like 
var index =callsData.findIndex(x => inArray('3432423423423',x.DestUniqueid))

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said, `obj.DestUniqueid.indexOf('3432423423423')` returns the index of 3432423423423 in the array (0-based) or -1 if it's not found. EDIT: `var index = callsData.DestUniqueid.indexOf('3432423423423'); // index is the correct index or -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write a simple `for loop`,

```
for(var i=0;i<callsData.length;i++){
  if(callsData[i].DestUniqueid.indexOf("3432423423423") > -1)
  break;
}

console.log(i + " is the index of element with value 3432423423423");
```

If you want it as a function then just write like,

```
function getIndex(val){
 for(var i=0;i<callsData.length;i++){
  if(callsData[i].DestUniqueid.indexOf(val) > -1)
   break;
 }
 return i;
}

console.log(getIndex("3432423423423") + " is the index of element with value 3432423423423");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ggk9enq6/)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the main array and upon each iteration, check the DestUniqueid property to see if it contains the value you seek:

```
function findIndex(valToFind){
 for(var i = 0; i < callsData.length; ++i){
   if(callsData[i].DestUniqueid.indexOf(valToFind) >= 0) {
       return i;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: should be `var myObject = [ ... ]` ..it's an array of object, not an object of objects. it it was an object your loop wouldn't work.

Comment: @Pamblam The OP has the main object enclosed in { }. This is object literal notation. WITHIN the object is a property that is storing an array as its value (DestUniqueid) and that is what my loop is looping over.

Comment: the object in the question is an example of what is in his array. you can't loop over an object like you've done here unless the properties all happened to have numeric sequential names. see the fiddle in the other answer to understand what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to accomplish that in linear time.

How large is the array? Is it sorted in any way?

```
function findIndex (array, target) {
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if (array[i].DestUniqueid) === target){
     return i;
   }
   return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array#find` function:

```
var index;

callsData.find(function(el, i) {
    if (el.DestUniqueid.indexOf('3432423423423') != -1) {
        index = i;
        return true;
    }
})

console.log(index); // index that you need
```

Also you can use `Array#filter` function to get all elements with `DestUniqueid` that you need:

```
var arr = callsData.filter(function(el){
     return el.DestUniqueid.indexOf('3432423423423') != -1;
});

console.log(arr); // array of callsData with your DestUniqueid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {
  "caller_id": "110",
  "Channel": "SIP/Kam-SBC-0000001c",
  "AccountCode": "1004",
  "Server": "192.168.1.36",
  "Callee": "109",
  "connected_line": "109",
  "Uniqueid": "145712272845",
  "DestChannel": "SIP/Kam-SBC-0000001d",
  "DestUniqueid": ["3432423423423","123123123","312321312"]
}

x.DestUniqueid.indexOf("3432423423423")
> 0
x.DestUniqueid.indexOf("312321312")
> 2
```

So you could just call index of in a function

```
var findIndex = function(obj, myVar){
   return obj.DestUniqueid.indexOf(myVar)
}
```

and call it like:

```
findIndex(x, "312321312")
>2
```